# Spring boot REST aplication return HTML insted of JSON and Angular aplication not recognize it

Tags: html, json, angular, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot aplication generated by https://start.spring.io/ and I can't get it to produce JSON instead of HTML, this is the code:

```
[@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200",maxAge=3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class UsuariosController {
@Autowired
    UsuariosService ser;
    @GetMapping(path = "/entrar/{usu}/{pass}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Usuarios entrar(@PathVariable("usu") String usu,@PathVariable("pass") String pass){
    return ser.comprobarPass(usu, pass);
}
```

}

And this is the result in Firefox web browser.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJvIJ.png)

this is de comprobarPass method:

```
    @Override
public Usuarios comprobarPass(String usu, String pass) {
    return rep.compruebaUsuariopass(usu, pass);
}}
```

this is the dependencies part of POM.XML:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
            </dependency>
 <dependency>
```

This is the Angular code:

```
    this.lo.verifyUserPass(this.usu,this.pass).subscribe((usua)=>{this.userloged=usua});
console.log("valor: "+this.userloged)
```

And this is the function:

```
  verifyUserPass(usu:string,pass:string){
return this.http.get<Usuarios>(this.path+"entrar/"+usu+"/"+sha512.sha512(pass));
```

}

And this is the output in firefox [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZDjW.png)

Comment: The result is missing but more important would be the URL you tried to access your app! PS: putting the password into the path is a security issue!

Comment: It is producing JSON ..what is your question ?

Comment: Ok, it looks like the “HTML” you mention is only internal Firefox rendering to display the JSON? Retry with curl to verify.

Comment: the password is SHA512 encripted

Comment: @PabloLleoGarcia Even a hashed password is an issue as it seems your API uses it to authenticate. BTW: SHA512 is a hashing method, not encryption, but that doesn’t matter here. And you also must never return a password in your response!

Comment: I will hide the hash in the response

Comment: curl http://localhost:8080/entrar/admin/c7ada0a452f9e854fdc1e0e7a52a38015f23f3eab1d80b931dd472634dfac71cd34ebc35d16ab7fb8a90c81f975113d6c7538dc69dd8de9077ec
{"id":1,"nombre":"Pedro","apellidos":"Perez Gonzalez","telefono":"12345678901","usuario":"admin","password":"c7ad44cbad762a5da0a452f9e854fdc1e0e7a52a38015f23f3eab1d80b931dd472634dfac71cd34ebc35d16ab7fb8a90c81f975113d6c7538dc69dd8de9077ec","admin":true}pablo@DESKTOP-LTPUOJJ:~$

Comment: Aparenly the curl works, but Angular not recognize it like JSON

Comment: Are there any configuration in Spring Boot server that are posible cause?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your return type is not a serializable object, and you can explicit your return type.

Try below code

```
[@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200",maxAge=3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class UsuariosController {
@Autowired
    UsuariosService ser;
    @GetMapping(path = "/entrar/{usu}/{pass}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Usuarios> entrar(@PathVariable("usu") String usu,@PathVariable("pass") String pass){
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(ser.comprobarPass(usu, pass));
}
```

And your pojo in serializable

```
public class Usuarios implements serializable{
    //your pojo 
    }
```

Comment: None of these are needed!

Comment: I can't import static org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.serializable; because  TypeFactory is strikethrough

Answer (score 0):

Now works with this code in Angular

```
this.lo.verifyUserPass(this.usu,this.pass).subscribe(usua=>{this.userloged=usua});
```